# Cordova/Phonegap SQLite plugin

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Does anyone know of a sqlite plugin that works with wp8?  I am using this plugin for android and ios, but it doesnt work with wp8, but works perfect with iOS and android

https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

Does anyone know of a plugin that will work with iOS, android and Windows Phone 8+?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to work well for all 3.

**Cordova/PhoneGap SQLitePlugin**

Plugin ID

com.triarc.sqliteplugin
Description
Native interface to SQLite for PhoneGap/Cordova. Allows you to use more storage and provides more flexibility than the standard Web SQL database (window.openDatabase).
Maintainers
nerumo
Platforms
android,  amazon-fireos,  ios,  wp8

http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.triarc.sqliteplugin

Comment: I used this one and it is great.  Supports iOS, Android and Windows now